# How to automate flutter mobile app using appium?

Tags: java, flutter, selenium, appium, bdd

Currently, I am working on automating flutter mobile apps. I have successfully designed a BDD cucumber Java framework with a login script that is working well. Then I tried automating other functionalities, but I couldn’t get the mobile elements locator values into Appium Inspector. Our Team I need your input on the following points.

1. Is it possible to automate flutter applications with the BDD Cucumber Java framework?
2. Is it possible to inspect all mobile elements of the flutter app using the appium inspector? Do any other way to inspect flutter app elements ?
3. Do we have any other options for automating Flutter apps?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use gherkin packages available on pub.dev to automate using BDD Cucumber.
   The tests will be written in dart.
2. As far as my finding, appium requires `accessibility-id` to interact with elements. In flutter you cannot set `accessibility-id` for widgets. I gave up after a few days of research. The [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17988) is still open.

Edit: Found [this](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/12919) as well that says semanticLabel can be used for resource-id.

4. Flutter has its own integration test package that you can use to automate your tests. It's very easy to implement.
   Read more here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. As per my understanding, Currently we can't automate flutter apps using appium locators ? And there is only one option to automate flutter app is DART

Comment: When I tried it, yes. There was no way to locate elements. But according to that article, you can use semanticLabels. Why not give that a try?

Comment: Other than that, the integration test package is the recommended way and it is pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it possible to automate flutter applications with the BDD Cucumber Java framework?

yes you can create the project Java + maven + cucumber + Junit or TestNg

2. Is it possible to inspect all mobile elements of the flutter app using the appium inspector? Do any other way to inspect flutter app elements ?

There are some limitations to find the elements by using the appium inspector.

Comment: yes you can use native context to inspect elements with appium inspector. the second way to inspect elements(Widgets)  use flutter inspector but you need to have access to source code and build app from android studio https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector